# Strange inequality with $\zeta(5)$

Tags: inequalities, riemann-zeta-function

$$\frac{\pi^2}{1+\exp(-1/\pi^2)}<\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{5}{k^5}<\frac{\pi^2}{1+\exp(-\pi/31)}$$
How can I prove it (not only with computation)?

Comment: Why do you believe it true?

Comment: $5.184588547 < 5.184638775 < 5.184639036$.

Answer (score 9):

This is not a problem, since each of the three terms of the inequality can be computed with any degree of accuracy. So, in Mathematica, we have

[image]

which proves the inequality.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can evaluate all three terms with, say *Mathematica*. Here are the values (with the totally unnecessary 100 digits of precision):

$$LHS = 5.18458854524983961500658690076805773926750300648649665898594174063399\
5627991695704036099550189522038$$

$$RHS = 5.18463903392322249336322731083508141376690784729947023393072904779669\
3557373710207062934426663089111$$

$$5\zeta(5) = 5.18463877571684963165682743228517084028540459750956405987096338951901\
7948931407422800215532785666682$$

This is a proof.